# Unrecognised font family after backgrounding the app

Tags: react-native

I am using Noto Serif Medium font. Everything works as it should, when I launch the app with a fresh start.

The issue happens when I background the app and open anything that has not been rendered yet.
The classic "Unrecognised font family" error appears.
This error happens on iOS emulator and iOS physical devices.

I have checked targets, resources and Info.plist file in Xcode. Everything is there. Still this error happens.

I suspect that there could be an issue with the .ttf file itself, as you're not able to get this font from Google Fonts directly, even though it is a free to use font.

Is there anyone that can provide a lead to a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This one was a dozzie.
Turns out, that it shouldn't have been working in a first place. It was a classical iOS font name issue. I don't know why it was working when the app wasn't backgrounded, but hey atleast the problem is solved.

Just use the PostScript name, not the real name tag in iOS fontbook.

[image: Font Book example]

Comment: I realize this is old, but did you use the PostScript name in ALL places? `Info.plist`, `link-assets-manifest.json` files, AND your runtime (e.g. `textUtils.ts` or whatever)?